# Signing an APK in Phonegap CLI

Tags: android, phonegap-cli

I am remaking one of my apps as a new Phonegap project, and I am having trouble getting it to sign the APK.

In the old project, I added release-signing.properties with this info, and when I run `phonegap build --release --verbose` I get a prompt asking for the keystore password:

```
storeFile=path/to/keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=aliasName
```

I copied this file to the new project, but it doesnt prompt for the password, and I get the error `com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key aliasName from store "path/to/keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

This is the same keystore and password for both apps, and I tried adding `--storePassword=...` and `--keyPassword=...` to the command with no change.

Adding `keyPassword` and `storePassword` to release-signing.properties works, but I dont want to leave the passwords in the project like that. What can I do to get it to prompt for the password?

I am using Phonegap 6.4.4 with Android platform 6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Android platform 6.x [[CB-12159] Android: Keystore password prompt won't show up - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12159)

Updating phonegap to 6.4.6 and Android platform to 6.1.2 fixed the issue

```
npm install -g phonegap
phonegap platform update android@latest
```